# How to revert colors in repeating-linear-gradient

Tags: css, gradient

I Have repeating-linear-gradient

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent 30px, #f3f3f3 30px, #f3f3f3 60px);
```

it starts with white color, and then it's grey.

```
white
grey
white
```

I want that this gradient starts with grey color!, how to change properties?
need this

```
grey
white
grey
```

Comment: invert the coloration?

Comment: yes! i want revert colors

Comment: do it then ... switch the colors inside the gradient

Comment: please give example, I try but can do anything

Comment: transparent insted of #f3f3f3 (and the opposite)

Comment: you should try more and do more effort before asking such question. A quick look to the documentation and you can understand how it works and how to create such basic gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#f3f3f3, #f3f3f3 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 60px);
```